# How do I merge a older feature branch with a newer main branch in git?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

Let me explain and in my defense, i just got access to this repo:
in this repository (GitLab) there is a `main` and `testing` branch. In the main branch is nothing but the initial readme.md. All the actual code is in the `testing` branch.
I want to merge the actual code into main.

Now the Problem:
The testing branch is older than the initial commit on main. (see [git branch graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQI0Z.png))

This is beacause the testing branch was from an older repo which was imported from GitHub.

I tried merging, but thats not possible because the branches do not have the same history.

I also tried a rebase but i've got merge issues in nearly every commit and not the knowledge and also time to go through each and everyone of them. (also tried -Xtheirs and -Xours but both resulted in different results than origin/testing)

I tried making a new local main branch and merging with local tetsing, but i wasn't able to push it to remote.

One Idea is just to delete main and rename testing to main but everywhere on the internet is written to NEVER delete the initial main branch.

What do I do?

Comment: Which branches do the colours in your graph image, represent?

Comment: Seems like whoever did the import to Github didn't do it correcty :/, is it to late to fix that? He should have changed the remote and pushed the entire history instead of just checking in the current state of the code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass the `--allow-unrelated-histories` flag to `git merge`, it will merge the two branches even though they have no common ancestor commits:

```
git checkout main
git merge --allow-unrelated-histories testing
```

Or, to perform the merge from the other side but still end up on `main`:

```
git checkout testing
git merge --allow-unrelated-histories main
git checkout -B main
```

Alternatively, you could do:

```
git checkout testing
git cherry-pick main
git checkout -B main
```

which will replay the single commit from `main` on top of `testing` and then forcibly move the `main` branch onto `testing`. This will preserve the contents of that commit but will make git think that there is no relation between the new commit and the original one (and the original one will eventually be garbage collected because nothing points to it).

Notes about some of the points you brought up:

- The *age* of the commits to be merged do not matter at all.
- From git's perspective, there is nothing special about `main`; it's just the default name for the initial branch. GitHub (and probably GitLab) does have a notion of a *default branch*, and will prevent you from deleting it in the remote repository, but you're free to (temporarily) delete it locally and recreate it somewhere else. Also, a commit does not know what branch it was made on, and a branch has no memory of which commits it was previously attached to, which is why the `cherry-pick` approach works even though it ends up discarding the original commit that `main` used to point to. When you push `main` to GitLab, GitLab will happily accept the new branch position and forget about the old commit.

Answer (score 0):

A. The `main` branch seems useless here. You could:

0. Create a `main_backup` branch from `main` and push that
1. Delete `main`.
2. Checkout `testing` and create a new `main` branch from it.

B. You could also just delete `main` and just work with `testing` and your central branch.